# Google app sheets: help description for optional arguments in custom functions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, jsdoc, optional-parameters, custom-function

For my custom functions, I cannot find a way to shows optional arguments in square brackets in Google sheets help window as in the figure.

[image: Figure]

Comment: Great. I'll close this question as a dupe. AFAIK, There's no known workaround. You can search the "issuetracker" or create a feature request there. I'll add a answer in the original question with tracker links. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more links.